# installation of fonts 0 KB

Tags: fonts

I am no computer enthusiast so I am sorry if this question is not right for this forum. I've had an InDesign package sent to me, but most fonts in the fonts folder are 0 KB, have no extension and I can't open them. I could install the rest of them, though. I have read that that may be because I unzipped the MAC package on Windows, and that I should ask for an "archive file" of the fonts. Is an archive file a compressed file? The package was already a zip file. Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a little hard to follow, but the 0 byte files are likely either folders or some form of placeholder.  An archive file is a collection of files stored inside a single file.  They are often compressed.  It's possible that some of the fonts were in a separate archive.  If so and you didn't get it, it sounds like you need to ask for it.  Can you clarify exactly what your concerns are?  There really isn't much information to go on.

Comment: In addition to what @fixer1234 has (correctly) stated - if they are in a compressed file is the compressed size 0kb? Have you uncompressed the package?

Comment: Thank you fixer1234 andRaystafarian, that was very clarifying.I need to install some fonts that have been senttome. They were sent inside a compressed package from MAC that I uncompressed on Windows. The package was not 0KB. It included other files  that I could open after uncompressing the package, which also included a fonts folder.Some of these fonts had some KB and I could install them,and their extensions were .otf or .ttf. The rest of thefonts had no extension and were 0kb.Maybe they are placeholders as you say,but then there is no separate file for them.I hope I explained myself better.

Comment: @gepeta: FYI, you need to "address" comments, like on this one, or nobody will be aware of your posting.  It's hard for anyone to know exactly what's going on without specifics on the package.  Whatever the details, it sounds like you just need to obtain an additional package that apparently wasn't provided originally.  It doesn't sound like anything is not working as it should.  It's possible that the missing fonts are ones that come on a Mac but not with Windows, so they're packaged separately in case you need them.

Comment: @fixer1234: Ok, thank you very much fixer1234, for all your comments. I'll ask for the additional package.

Comment: @fixer1234: Is there a way I can vote for your answers? I looked at the help but cant find a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the thought but they're only comments, glad to help.  Post back and let us know if you're successful or if you need further help.  Good luck.

Comment: @fixer1234:They said I just work with the uninstalled fonts on InDesign, so  that's easier for me. Would have liked to get that additional package though. Sorry for all the trouble

Answer (score 5):

I came across some strange 0-byte fonts too.  I found this explanation:

> Back in OS 9 Mac fonts used to store their data in the resource fork. Normally this is used for storing metadata about a file. Someone at Apple decided that putting fonts in there was a good idea. Now in OS X the resource fork has been moved to the extended attribute `com.apple.ResourceFork`. Extended attributes are not used in file size calculations by terminal. If you want to see the extended attributes you can use `xattr -l file_name`. Running that on the font file showed a giant chunk of data in com.apple.ResourceFork that was definitely the font info. Mystery solved.

Source: http://www.dmertl.com/blog/?p=11

One way to solve this is to extract the metadata to a file, like this:

`xattr -p com.apple.ResourceFork file_name > file_name.ttf`

Comment: "Someone at Apple decided…" – I'd love to know their reasoning.

Comment: Convert all files without extensions in current directory to non-resource-fork TTF (you might need to convert extension ones too): `for file in !(*.*); do xattr -p com.apple.ResourceFork "$file" | xxd -r -p  > "${file}.ttf"; done`  (NOTE: `xxd -r -p` was missing from answer via source.) Can confirm still works in Mojave.

Comment: Actually no, it only sorta kinda works. The resulting fonts load in some contexts, not others.